# How to specify a docstring for a c++ class in pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

Suppose I have a c++ class and want it to be available in Python using pybind11.
Is there notation for specifying a docstring for the class?
For example, this doesn't work:

```
  py::class_<Edge>(m, "Edge")
      .doc("An Edge is used for representing an edge of a graph.")
      .def(py::init<int>())
```

apparently because the `doc` method takes no arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
      py::class_<Edge>(m, "Edge")
          .def(py::init<int>())
          .doc() = "An Edge is used for representing an edge of a graph.";
}
```

This is also valid:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
      py::class_<Edge>(m, "Edge");

      m.def(py::init<int>());

      m.doc() = "An Edge is used for representing an edge of a graph.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can you show how that fits with the rest of the code?  I don't understand the scoping of `m`.

Comment: @pnklein edited to show it fits:
"The second argument (m) defines a variable of type py::module_ which is the main interface for creating bindings". `m` has the scope of the macro `PYBIND11_MODULE` which presumably you are using to export the class to Python.